# Related to usage of dll in java

Tags: java, dll, function-pointers

I have a dll which is developed in 'C'.
I need to use it in my Java program.
My problem is like this:
I need to call a function of dll which has structure variable as one of its parameter from java program.
How to do it?
can i pass object as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet -- given that I suspect this is Windows-only -- is to use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), which will let you use the DLL entirely from Java, without writing any custom C code. JNA does indeed handle function objects of `struct` type, using a special `Structure` Java class.